# Flutter: Avoid wallpaper streching across multiple screens

Tags: android, flutter, android-wallpaper

I'm using a Wallpaper Manager for setting an image as Home screen. It works fine for Lock Screen, but not for Home screen. This image that I want to set as Home screen is as wide and long as the screen, so it gets blurred when stretched across multiple screens. I'd like for this image to be repeated on each screen, not stretched across all. Is there any solution? I'm open to any idea, even if it doesn't include wallpaper manager.

Answer (score 0):

I get it too, bro. But this package have a function called **setWallpaperFromFileWithCrop**
so you can let user crop image to set wallpaper as you want.

Comment: Hi ninoorta, could you please set setWallpaperFromFileWithCrop function in Bold style to bring more attention to it when your answer is read by others. Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: thank you for reminding me @AshrafAlshahawy

Comment: please more description about what package ? i only 've ```WallpaperManagerFlutter().setwallpaperfromFile``` there is no ```setWallpaperFromFileWithCrop``` i use `wallpaper_manager_flutter: ^0.0.2`